# how to insert record that has . in the key using insertOne() mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

After investigating got to know that we can use bypass_document_validation. however, I am getting an error: True is not defined. My mongodb version is 3.5.9. can anyone please let me know what is the issue?

object contains following data:

6023f6ae3601233c080b1365/spe10_lgr311_2021-03-10_17-14-02/output/spe10_lgr311_copy1.err:'51fa1bdd-a680-4679-9a97-8278b141daed'
useremail:'fsasdev@xxx.com'
userid:'2932fb99-4c41-4342-99e0-af15f8146da0'

db.collectionname.insertOne(object,bypass_document_validation=True,..)

Answer (score 0):

**insertOne** doesn't seems to be supported. and when u use boolean, you need to use `true` instead of `True`.

> Users can bypass document validation on commands and methods that
> support the bypassDocumentValidation option. The following commands
> and their equivalent methods support bypassing document validation:
>
> aggregate
>
> applyOps
>
> findAndModify
>
> insert
>
> mapReduce
>
> update
>
> Apply this action to database or collection resources.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/privilege-actions/

Also using `.` in key is only supported in 3.6

Top-level field names cannot start with the dollar sign ($) character.

> Otherwise, starting in MongoDB 3.6, the server permits storage of
> field names that contain dots (i.e. .) and dollar signs (i.e. $).

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/#Restrictions-on-Field-Names

Comment: tried 3.6.0 but still getting the same error,insertOne(object,bypass_document_validation=true,

Comment: you are using this in mongo client? firstly i don't think it works with `insertOne`. secondly i think it should be `bypassDocumentValidation`